# Java simple process builder issue

Tags: java, linux, bash, processbuilder

I just conducted simple test code for Java Process Builder.
There are 4 examples and everything is working smoothly excluding last one.
Here is my codes

```
public class bashProcessor {

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
  ProcessBuilder pb;

  pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "touch Jin_1.sh");
  pb.start();

  pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "mkdir Jin_2");
  pb.start();

  pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "bash /home/Jin/test.sh");
  pb.start();

  //below is not working
  pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c",
      "bash /home/solr-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh warm4 solr-instances");

  pb.start();

  System.out.println("pb job is done now");

  Thread.sleep(3000);

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
 }
 }
```

When I type last example(bash /home/solr...) by hand-typing. It works without any error. I need your kind help. if you have any idea 
please let me know it would be great help.

Comment: Have you tried `"/bin/bash", "-c","bash", "/home/solr-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh", "warm4", "solr-instances"`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I just tried this as you said "pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "bash", "/home/solr-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh", "warm4", "solr-instances");" but It is not working either

Comment: Is there any reason your calling bash from inside bash? Maybe just simplify it to `("/home/solr-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh warm4 solr-instances");` or including the full path to bash from inside your script `("/bin/bash", "-c",
      "/bin/bash /home/solr-tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh warm4 solr-instances")`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried all provided command above. but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ug_ try to remove `bash` from command and then execute your code. Following code works fine with multiple command.

**cmd.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class cmd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
                String[] command = new String[3];
                command[0] = "/bin/bash";
                command[1] = "-c";
                command[2] = "javac -verbose HelloWorld.java";


                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                String Error;

                while ((Error = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(Error);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```